# Refactoring on IntelliJ - Maven dependencies issues

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

I tried to refactor -> rename my project, a few packages and classes. Unfortunately, I probably did something wrong at some point as I haven't been able to run anything anymore, getting a XMLPullParserException (see stack below...sorry, it's lengthy).

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 25 more
```

It feels like it's something really stupid I'm overlooking. I tried to solve the error by adding new dependancies in my POM.xml, only to end up stuck with yet another similar error, on a different class, while it used to run with a much smaller POM.xml with no issues, making me wonder how to check what could have gone wrong with my Maven dependancies, but to no avail.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bea/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactoryBase

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bea.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactoryBase
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 25 more
```

Here's the current POM.xml I have :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>SCMT2</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumCucumTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SeleniumCucumTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
          <artifactId>webdriver-common</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.7376</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
          <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
          <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.bea.xml</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr173-ri</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jbi-api-1.0</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>xom</groupId>
          <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No class def found is mainly the class is missing in manifest file for export. Please check that.

Comment: You should be able to look at the history from the `VCS` menu. Select the file you want to look at or the complete project & `VCS --> Local History --> Show History..`

Comment: @StackFlowed : as of now, I don't have a manifest file. The entire project is on my computer.
Amit : quite handful indeed, unfortunately, it seems to be able to show only the past 12 hours. I've been trying to find it on my own for a while now and can't revert to prior I made all the changes to my project...

Comment: do a `mvn clean install` on the project. Then try it should fi the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedbacks everyone. But the truth was elsewhere.
I simply (and very stupidly) refactored the package containing one of my class and renamed it "cucumber". Turns out that was a very bad idea.

There's a more detailed explanation for this here : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/934

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the installed package from maven repo. (.m2\repository) Also, if you don't use CVS for removed files check the local history of the idea it may help.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/